# What is the difference between LLD and Object Oriented Design?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, system, system-design

What is low level design and object oriented design? Design patterns are part of Object oriented design? Suggest me the best ways to learn about the low level design.

what are all the things will come under low level design?

Comment: I'd never heard of LLD before; but there is a short Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_design

Answer (score 1):

According to resources online and my personal experience, the only design pattern from the 2 is Object Oriented Design.

In regards to Low Level Design, from what I understand, this is more reminiscent of a requirements/software specification. Basically, this means that LLD Document can be a guide to help the programmer understand the 'how' of a program . This is usually in a form to help the programmer very easily come up with an implementation and can include properties of the various programs/classes such as:

- State in-variants
- Detailed design assumptions
- Exported types/constants
- Data structures used

Edit: Please correct me if I have missed something.

Answer (score -2):

Low-Level Design:
Low-level design (LLD) is a phase in the software design process that focuses on converting the high-level design into detailed, implementable instructions for the software development team. It deals with the internal logic of the system and specifies how each component or module should function at a detailed level. Low-level design is closer to the implementation and often involves defining algorithms, data structures, and interface specifications.

Object-Oriented Design (OOD):
Object-oriented design is a design paradigm that uses objects, which are instances of classes, to model real-world entities. It promotes concepts such as encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism. OOD is a higher-level design approach that often precedes low-level design. It helps in organizing and structuring the code in a way that makes it more modular, reusable, and maintainable.

Design Patterns:
Design patterns are general reusable solutions to common problems encountered in software design. They are not specific to a particular problem or implementation but provide templates for solving similar design issues. Design patterns can be part of object-oriented design, as they often involve creating and interacting with objects in a specific way to achieve a particular goal.

Learning Low-Level Design:
To learn low-level design, you can follow these steps:

Understand Basic Concepts: Familiarize yourself with basic concepts like data structures, algorithms, and system architecture.

Learn a Programming Language: Choose a programming language you are comfortable with or one commonly used in your domain. Understand its features and limitations.

Study Design Principles: Learn about design principles like SOLID (Single Responsibility, Open-Closed, Liskov Substitution, Interface Segregation, Dependency Inversion), which guide good object-oriented design.

Practice Design Exercises: Solve design problems and practice converting high-level requirements into detailed designs. This could involve designing specific modules or systems.

Read Design Books: There are several books on software design that cover both high-level and low-level design. Examples include "Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" by Gamma et al. and "Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship" by Robert C. Martin.

Low-Level Design Components:
Under low-level design, you typically work on:

Algorithms: Define the step-by-step procedures for solving specific problems.

Data Structures: Choose appropriate data structures to store and manipulate data efficiently.

Interfaces: Specify how different components/modules will interact with each other.

Database Design: Define the structure of the database, including tables, relationships, and queries.

Flowcharts and Pseudocode: Use flowcharts or pseudocode to represent the detailed logic of the system.

Class Diagrams: If using an object-oriented approach, create class diagrams that show the relationships between different classes.

Dependency Diagrams: Illustrate dependencies between different components/modules.

Remember, learning low-level design is an iterative process, and hands-on practice is crucial for gaining proficiency.